# Back To Top with ListView not working as intended

Tags: android, listview

In my app I have a `Button` on click of which it should take user to the top row of `ListView`

Code:

```
goTopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          lvItems.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
        }
    });
```

It does not work as intended. It sometimes takes user just few rows up, sometimes just half screen, sometimes to the top most row. I think this is because of varying size of row(elements like TextView having longer text?).

Xml for the Button

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/topButton"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="To Top"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/go_to_top" />
```

Anyone has any idea how can I go to top of the list irrespective of number of rows?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `listView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();`. It worked for me.